# Which strings should I use for DADGAD tuning on my acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings, alternative-tunings

I have recently switched to DADGAD tuning, before that I was using light tension strings ( 12 16 24 32 42 53 ).
But because of DADGAD, to compensate for the lack of tension on the neck, I wanted to switch to a mix of medium and light strings, puting higher tension strings on the ones that are lowered, resulting in ( 13 17 24 32 42 56 ), some friends playing DADGAD even used 14 and 18 for the two higher strings.

I wondered what you DADGAD players used?

And of course the economic side of it, buying one light set and one medium set and throwing away half the strings is not a very good solution, do you have any DADGAD-ready set to recommend?

Comment: I don't think we need a specific DADGAD tag at the moment, if we get more questions on this I'll be sure to add it back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you would like to get scientific about it, the D'Addario company has a chart discussing string tension and tuning and string gauges for alternate tuning schemes.

http://daddario.com/DAstringtensionguide.Page?ActiveID=2681

You can also download this PDF which explains the recommended tuning, pitches and tensions for every type and gauge of individual string that they sell.

http://www.daddario.com/upload/tension_chart_13934.pdf

D'Addario also sells a packaged set for acoustic guitar designed for DADGAD.

[D'Addario Acoustic Guitar Phosphor Bronze True Medium DADGAD Tuning .013 - .056, EJ24](http://store.daddario.com/category/414960/EJ24_True_Medium__DADGAD_Tuning_.013-.056)

```
                     Diameter        Tension
                   -------------   ------------
    Item#   Note   Inches   Mm     Lbs    Kg
    -------------------------------------------
    PL013   E      0.013    0.33   27.4   12.42
    PL017   B      0.017    0.43   26.3   11.91
    PB024   G      0.024    0.61   30.2   13.38
    PB032   D      0.032    0.81   30.5   13.83
    PB042   A      0.042    1.07   29,9   13.56
    PB056   E      0.056    1.42   29.0   13.15
```

Comment: That link is dead but the set is still available here: https://www.daddario.com/products/guitar/acoustic-guitar/phosphor-bronze/ej24-phosphor-bronze-acoustic-guitar-strings-true-medium-13-56/ Also, the table here shows tension figures for EADGBE tuning where DADGAD tension figures would be more useful.  The new string tension calculator gives me (high to low) 21.76  20.89  30.06  29.93  28.93  22.03 (lbs)

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously an extremely old post, but still worth answering for anyone who might be reading as this question still comes up when you Google "DADGAD strings":

A lot of players do play just fine with a normal set of standard 12s or 13s tuned to DADGAD (11s tuned down might feel a too floppy for an acoustic player, and I've found them a little more liable to break when strumming with a pick, and have never had any issue like that on 12s).

However, preselected sets tailor-made for DADGAD have become a bit more common, so you don't need to go out a create a custom set which can be more expensive, or worse, throw out a whole pack's worth of strings, which is the worst case scenario imo.

D'addario make a set of their regular phosphor bronze acoustic strings especially for DADGAD, called EJ24. Given how widespread the brand is, these seem to be quite readily available in music stores despite being a bit niche.
https://www.daddario.com/products/guitar/acoustic-guitar/phosphor-bronze/ej24-phosphor-bronze-acoustic-guitar-strings-true-medium-13-56/

The only other brand I see making them are these by Lowden, though I have no experience using them so I don't know what they're like.
https://shop-gb.lowdenguitars.com/products/lowden-strings-dadgad-13-56

Couldn't find many other similar sets out there myself, but I'm sure a few other brands may do them.

Comment: Any idea for a set for electric guitar?

Answer (score 1):

When I played in DADGAD tuning, it was one of several tunings I would use, so it never crossed my mind to use different strings.  But if this is something you want to do, I'd suggest constructing your own custom set with single strings rather than buying two sets and discarding the extra strings.

[Just Strings](http://www.juststrings.com/) sells individual strings from a variety of manufacturers.  Maybe you can find the brand you like in [this list](http://www.juststrings.com/guitarsinglestrings.html) from their site.

Comment: this is great link, Their prices are good too, and they sell single Elixir strings! Unfortunately, the shipment cost for Europe (40$) is prohibitive...

Comment: Try StringBusters.com in the UK