# String gauge, scale, and tuning relationship? (Guitar in particular)

Tags: guitar, theory, tuning, alternative-tunings, string-instruments

Does anyone have general guidance or a good resource on this, specifically considering scale length, string tension, string gauge, and tuning? I've found loads of anecdotal research and a even few calculators, but while these are often useful they don't actually explain the technical aspects or anything. I suppose I'm either looking for some sort of guide/explanation, the math behind it, and any helpful extraneous information you might have.

If it helps at all, I'm starting to get into non-standard tunings (major thirds in particular) and I'm trying to figure out why specific string gauges feel and/or sound 'better' than others from a technical standpoint.

Comment: Have you seen [this guide from D'Addario](http://daddario.com/upload/tension_chart_13934.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, but while it has a good section on string tension and an overall product guide, it doesn't really explain how everything works together, nor their effects on playability or tone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does string gauge affect a guitar's sound and playability?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/how-does-string-gauge-affect-a-guitars-sound-and-playability)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think so, as, while there is some overlap in the question, I'm not specifically asking how the gauge itself affects tone, at least not so much as asking how all the elements that affect tuning and tension work together and how they affect the tone and feel of an instrument. In addition, the top response by slim seems to fall under the category of 'anecdotal research.' I'm not saying it's a bad answer, and I agree with his responses, he doesn't actually explain any of it.

Comment: How objective an assessment are you expecting for *"why specific string gauges feel and/or sound 'better'"*? A good starting point would be to work out the string tensions at concert pitch with the strings you normally use, then identify gauges that provide similar tension at the altered pitch - this would give a consistent feel, at least.

Comment: -And would be kind to the neck of your guitar !

Comment: @jonrsharpe the main idea of my question is to understand the relationship between the strings, scale length, and tuning, not to find some sort of sweet spot for tuning. I'm more interested in A) choosing the right gauges for particular tensions at particular tunings B) finding the actual math/physics behind it all. When I said "I'm trying to figure out why specific string gauges feel and/or sound 'better' than others" I meant that having the mechanics explained would help me understand, not that I wanted people's opinions.

Comment: I think the answers you want are here: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-do-i-use-string-gauge-tables?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a really technical discussion that uses serious math, you can get 
Richard Mark French, *Engineering the Guitar*. (It's available as an ebook on Kindle.) He deals with scale length, intonation, the physics of ideal and real strings, etc., etc. The math is, frankly, beyond me, but it is an exhaustive treatment.

Answer (score 0):

See [this previous post of mine](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/which-strings-should-i-use-for-dadgad-tuning-on-my-acoustic-guitar/3716#3716).

And [this one from @slim](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-do-i-use-string-gauge-tables?lq=1).

They both refer you to a PDF guide published by the D'Addario String Company which provides a comprehensive resource for determining which gauges strings to use for different guitar-family instruments of different scale lengths and tuning schemes. It also takes into account different types of strings, such as steel-string and nylon. The charts and measurements generally can be used for any brand of strings, not just D'Addario's. This is a gold mine of information.

Comment: I have seen that guide before, I was looking for a resource that actually goes through and explains the relationship between tuning, scale, tension, and string gauge. While the D'Addario has a partial explanation on pages 4 and 5 it doesn't seem to cover everything.